# Frequently updating widgets (more frequently than what updatePeriodMillis allows)

Tags: android, android-widget

I want a widget showing a countdown for a user initiated tracking of a bus departure. I want to update the widget every minute or so, from when the user initiates the tracking to when the bus has departed (i.e. the time runs out).

This widget needs to be updated more frequently than what `updatePeriodMillis` allows, which is every 30 minutes. I reckon about once a minute.

Being new to Android programming, I can think of a few ways to do this, but I would probably end up doing it in a way that consumes way too much battery etc, so I'm looking for some insights from more experienced Android developers.

How do I start the timer? How can I access the widget instance from my applications run-time? And so on.

Comment: FYI, `updatePeriodMillis` update frequency is 30 **minutes**, not seconds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would register an alarm to start my service every 1 minute and the service would update the widget UI

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pending);
long interval = 1000*60;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pending);
```

AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME will not wakr the device if it's sleeping to battery life should not be affected.

Comment: "I would register an alarm" - Where does that code go?  Where do you register the `AlarmManager`?

Comment: @jjnguy The AlarmManager does not need to be registered, as it's received from `context.getSystemService`.

Comment: This is not helpful at all! Where does all of this code go? For a beginner using widget, there is no use of that to make...

Comment: is this should be put where the class is extended to `AppWidgetProvider`. On `onUpdate` method?

Comment: Virthuss / @natsumiyu, It goes into the user interaction where you know you need to start updating. Don't forget to cancel the repeating alarm once the rapid refresh is not necessary any more. Don't forget that you also need to implement a service to send an update intent to yourself, which is not listed here.