# Android: How to run thread in Service after timely intervals?

Tags: android

Hi
I need to create a service that runs a piece of code in new thread after (let us say) 10 mins. How can I do that? I have service ready but I don't seem to understand how (if ) to call timer from within thread. can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some (more) searching on StackOverFlow I found something that helps me

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
                {
                    // code here what ever is required
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10*600);
                }
            };

   handler.postDelayed(r, 10*600);
```

Comment: Handler will run this runnable instance in UI thread. How to do it for background thread??

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create new Handler. You get new thread and you can execute code defined in Runnable `handleMyAction` after 10 minutes:

```
mMessageHandler.postDelayed(handleMyAction, 1000*600);
```

Comment: How about this: Thread thread = new Thread()
  {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              while(true) {
                  sleep(1000);
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Running Thread...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
  };

thread.start();

Comment: What I suggested to you is exactly what you have found alone some time later.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on timer. You service may be killed during these 10 minutes and timer will be destroyed. The reliable way is to use AlarmManager [Frequently updating widgets (more frequently than what updatePeriodMillis allows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310264/frequently-updating-widgets-more-frequently-than-what-updateperiodmillis-allows/3310343#3310343)