# How to force a background refresh for an android app?

Tags: android

I use Evernote at work and for some reason, I need the note widget to auto-update every 5 min, the problem is the app only allow 15 mins auto-update which means I need to open the app every 5 min to get the note updated. Any way to "force" an auto background app update? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

App widgets in android has limit to the frequency of the updates to not drain the battery of the phone. To get around this you can try the answer on this question: [Frequently updating widgets (more frequently than what updatePeriodMillis allows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310264/frequently-updating-widgets-more-frequently-than-what-updateperiodmillis-allows)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why does email widget like gmail and outlook allow auto update when a new mail arrives?

Comment: I would guess that they have implemented a refresh when a push notification arrives with a new email.